# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que una WebApp hecha en Laravel 10 pueda autenticar el formulario de Login a través de una API que ya tengo lista?

Tags: laravel, api

¿Cómo puedo hacer que una WebApp hecha en Laravel 10 pueda autenticar el formulario de Login a través de una API que ya tengo lista?

Hasta el momento sigo usando el sistema nativo que trae Laravel para autenticar usuarios por email y password y quisiera saber si alguien lo ha hecho de la forma en que lo quisiera yo y me pudiera orientar o explicar por favor como lograrlo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: como que tipo de comentarios haces referencia? creo que el problema esta descrito segun mi percepcion, pero agradeceré tu orientación para que por favor me indiques que debo agregar